PowerBI - Creating Buttons With Pre-Set Advanced Filters for ALL Visual On a Page
I need to create 2 buttons for my report which filter ALL of the visuals on my page based on multiple conditions. I have tried using bookmarks with buttons but my issue is that you can only use bookmarks with slicers and my conditions are slightly complex.
I need to filter my visuals in two ways.

Low Performing:

This should apply the following conditions
' Count of Patients < 2' && 'Count of Patients > 0 '

Non Performing:

This should apply the following conditions
-'Count of Patients = 0'
OR
-'Start Date IS NOT blank && Count of Patients is either blank OR Count of Patients <1'
So I want two buttons on my page that will each filter my data based on the conditions above. If a viewer was to select 'Non-Performing' button they will see a filtered view of the data where EITHER the patient count is 0 OR where there is a non blank start date AND the count of patients is either 0 or blank. If a viewer was to select 'Low-Performing' button they will see a filtered view of the data where the patient count is less than 2 but more than 0.
I have been struggling to recreate this. Firstly I tried to use slicers and then hiding them, and then adding a bookmark to the button but I couldn't create a slicer for the non performing.
Secondly, I created a new table which had one column with the two filter names (low and non performing). I then wrote a measure to attempt to include these filters - but the issue with this was that I could only apply it to one visual not the entire page.
ANY and all suggestions welcome. I have become super frustrated figuring this out and I am sure that I am overcomplicating this....
Thanks :)
CODE for the measure:
BUTTONMeasure =
VAR Cur_Sel=
SELECTEDVALUE('Buttons'[Preset Code])
 
VAR _Site =
SELECTEDVALUE('Historical Study by Site & PI'[Site])
 
VAR _a =
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Historical Study by Site & PI'[Site]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Historical Study by Site & PI'),
        'Historical Study by Site & PI'[Count Patients Randomised] <2
        && 'Historical Study by Site & PI'[Count Patients Randomised] >0
    )
)
 
VAR _b =
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Historical Study by Site & PI'[Site]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Historical Study by Site & PI'),
        'Historical Study by Site & PI'[RTE] <> BLANK()
        && 'Historical Study by Site & PI'[Count Patients Screened] <1
    )
)
 
VAR _c =
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Historical Study by Site & PI'[Site]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Historical Study by Site & PI'),
        'Historical Study by Site & PI'[Count Patients Screened]=0
    )
)
 
 
VAR _val =
SWITCH(
    Cur_Sel,
    "Low Performing Sites", IF (_Site IN _a,1),
    "Non Performing Sites", IF (_Site IN _b && _Site IN _c,1)
)
 
RETURN
IF ( ISFILTERED(Buttons[Preset Code]), _val,1)

EXAMPLE Data Table:



Name
Address
Count Patients
Start Date




George
123 lane
4
19/01/2022


Julia
456 Street
0
01/01/2020


Nathan
829 Av

02/01/2024


Felicity
43rd Street





